# Remove Sharepoint Theme from Custom Master Page

Tags: 2013

I have created a custom master page in which I want zero SharePoint styles to be applied. I have tried adding `visible="false"` to the `<SharePoint:CssLink>` but that prevents my custom stylesheet from loading.

How do I get SharePoint 2013 to still load custom stylesheets without loading the SharePoint theme css?

Because if I remove or add `visible="false"` to the `<SharePoint:CssLink>` then my styles are never loaded.

Answer (score 0):

To add your custom CSS files on your custom master page, use can use the "**SharePoint:CssRegistration**" tag.

You can place your custom CSS file within SharePoint.

Here is an example:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="mysampleID" name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/siteassets/styles/myfolder/mycustom.css %&gt;" runat="server" after="somespecificfilehereifneeded.css"/>
```

Detailed info can be found [here](http://yakovenkomax.com/cssregistration-and-scriptlink-done-the-right-way/)